# order results based on join conditions order

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

There are 3 mysql tables.

```
BOOKS have ID, AUTHOR1, AUTHOR2, PUBLISHER1, PUBLISHER2
AUTHORS have ID, WEBSITE
PUBLISHERS have ID, WEBSITE
```

Not all publishers or authors have a website.

I have a query that returns matching sets of author and publisher websites for a given book ID. If they all have a website, this would mean 2 rows.

```
SELECT AUTHORS.WEBSITE as WEB1, PUBLISHERS.WEBSITE as WEB2
FROM BOOKS
LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTHORS ON (ID=AUTHOR1 OR ID=AUTHOR2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLISHERS ON (ID=PUBLISHER1 OR ID=PUBLISHER2)
WHERE BOOK.ID ='12345'
LIMIT 2
```

While this works, it ends up returning the row matching the second author and publisher before the first author and publisher. Possibly based on alphabetical order.

How can I make this query return the row containinting the websites of AUTHOR1 and PUBLISHER1 first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd treat them as separate joins and use a COALESCE.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A1.WEBSITE, A2.WEBSITE) as WEB1, 
       COALESCE(P1.WEBSITE, P2.WEBSITE) as WEB2
FROM BOOKS B
LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTHORS A1 ON A1.ID=B.AUTHOR1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTHORS A2 ON A2.ID=B.AUTHOR2
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLISHERS P1 ON P1.ID=B.PUBLISHER1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLISHERS P2 ON P2.ID=B.PUBLISHER2
WHERE B.ID ='12345'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you left the limit at 2?

Comment: @Enkay: Removed it. It was just leftover from copy/pasting your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no order by clause in the query, you can be sure that results being ordered alphabetically is just plain coincidence.

Anyway

```
SELECT AUTHORS.WEBSITE as WEB1, PUBLISHERS.WEBSITE as WEB2
FROM BOOKS
LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTHORS ON (ID=AUTHOR1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLISHERS ON (ID=PUBLISHER1)
WHERE BOOK.ID ='12345'
UNION
SELECT AUTHORS.WEBSITE as WEB1, PUBLISHERS.WEBSITE as WEB2
FROM BOOKS
LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTHORS ON (ID=AUTHOR2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLISHERS ON (ID=PUBLISHER2)
WHERE BOOK.ID ='12345'
LIMIT 2
```